# תדיר vs. טרחה ציבור on Rosh Chodesh Chanukah - which wins?

Tags: halacha-theory, chanuka, torah-reading, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Tomorrow is Rosh Chodesh & Chanukah, together. Two Sifrei Torah are taken out.

The rule of תדיר specifies that we read from Rosh Chodesh first, since Rosh Chodesh occurs more frequently than Chanukah.

Let's say, they accidentally placed the Chanukah Torah down on the table, first. We cannot just place this Torah back and switch it with the other one without reading for it as doing this would be considered an embarrassment to the Torah. Yet, if we roll this Torah as well as the other one (which is now on Rosh Chodesh, and would have to be rolled to the Chanukah section), this is טרחה ציבור - (burdening the congregation.)

May one reverse the reading in this situation to avoid טרחה ציבור? Would he be allowed to do this if let's say there were exactly 10 people in shul, and one person said that he must leave to go to work by a certain time, and rolling the Torah would cause him to miss his train. If he leaves, you will have no Minyan for Musaph.

Comment: If 45 seconds is really the difference for him, there are way better things to skip on then this. Cut the Misheberachs, putting the Torah away, uva letzion, maybe second hagbah, and go straight to hechi kedusha musaf. The claim is pretty ridiculous though.  After all you're only rolling 20 columns or so. You can probably do it entirely while calling up the kohein.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%93_%D7%92

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, why is just swapping the scrolls an "embarrassment", if it will be used shortly afterwords?

Comment: @Aba The concern is removing it now may cause people to suspect it has been declared invalid.

Comment: Happy Chanukah, @DoubleAA. I'm not sure what to deduce from that link. It seems to describe what to do after he started reading. Here, the reading didn't start. Logically, it seems that the best option is to read the first from the Chanukah, then the next 4 from Rosh Chodesh. Am I getting that right?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have no problem deleting this theoretical claim, if you think it improves the question. It is tangential to the rest of the question which focuses on the "theory" of which wins

Comment: The Mishna Brura @DoubleAA referenced (see bottom of page) says אבל אם לא התחיל לברך אף שנזדמן בידם אותה שהוא מתוקן לחנוכה אין לו לחוש לזה לכו"ע ויגללוה ויקראו בס"ת אחרת שהוציאוה לשם ר"ח ואין כאן פגם לס"ת זו כיון שיקראו בה אח"כ [אחרונים] if you didn't start to say the barchos  you can swap. I therefore assume we only worry about invalid not to put it back in the Arron Kodesh